# How to check if the text content of a cell represents zero in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose a cell has text `"0.00"`. What formula can I use to check that the text represents zero?

Curiously, both `to_pure_number(to_text(0))` and `to_pure_number("0.00")` outputs `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--` to suppress number stored as text to actual numeric values. Like-

```
=--A1
```

Then you can use `ISNUMBER()` to check it like-

```
=ISNUMBER(--A1)
```